# Android app development sending emails with multiple strings

Tags: android, string, email, android-intent

So I want the body of my email to reference 5 Edit texts. I already have those set up and I want the body to be like:

```
Name: [Name]

Phone: [Phone]

Detailed Description: [Description]
```

So all I need help with is telling it to paste the strings like above.
My code Currently as far as Body goes:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Name);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Phone);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Email);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, BigDesc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the message text using fields coming from the UI. You should try somethig like this:

```
String message = "Name: " editTextName.getText() + "\n\n\nPhone: " + editTextPhone.getText() + "\n\n\n\n\n\nDetailed Description: " + editTextDesc.getText();

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
```

Is it what you need?